# How to check if post/page or taxonomy post is published by admin

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, admin, conditional-tags

Example :- 10 users and 2 admin in a site.

If the post is published by admins than

```
<?php ?????() { ?>
  <!-- do this -->   
  <?php } 
  else { ?>
   <!-- do this if posted by user --> 
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: When do you want this to work? When a user is logged in and publishes a post OR a post is already published and you wan to check the author?

Comment: Please, don't cross-post... http://stackoverflow.com/q/11310023/1287812

Comment: If is post/page is not published by admin than show the User/Author name. If the post is published by Admin than not to show anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be simple as:

```
global $post;
if ( user_can( $post->post_author, 'manage_options' )){
    // this is an admin
} else {
    // this is not
}
```

*Assuming the only admins on your site can manage options.*

Comment: If is post/page is not published by admin than show the User/Author name to any visitor (Not necessary it has to be a logged in user). If the post is published by Admin than not to show anything. And their are many user in the site in which 2 admins, 4 editor and other are contributes. Thanks for the help +Bainternet & +Kaiser